# iPhone camera portrait mode colors are wrong

Tags: iphone, camera

My brother has an iPhone 7+ and for some reason sometimes when he is talking pictures using the portrait mode the colors are just off, not close to the colors that are in real life.

One picture of him outdoors is literally looking like sepia effect over it.

He has only used the portrait mode on the main camera of the phone.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's almost impossible to provide a good answer because your question is missing some important info.  You say this happens "for some reason sometimes" so that implies it doesn't always happen.  That means it's probably something he's doing when taking a picture, like accidentally hitting the filter button with his finger.  Unless it happens with every picture then it's probably not hardware related.

Comment: Also clean the front camera.

Comment: @ankii iPhone 7 does not support Portrait mode with the front camera, this requires iPhone X or later.

Comment: Sorry, it is not the front camera, is the main camera . When the pictures are taken inside , the portrit mode seems to work fine, when the pictures are taken outside using this mode, thats where this is happening

Comment: @fsb, how can u accidentally hit on the filter button. sorry I dont have an iphone so not sure how this works

Comment: The filter button is on the top right corner.  Depending on how you hold the iPhone, buttons can be hit accidentally.  You're not able to provide enough info for a more detailed analysis.